# Which MiniZinc-compatible solvers are best suited for floating decision variables and non-linear constraints?

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc, continuous-optimization

We are working on a production scheduling problem that has both discrete ("how much to produce from good x and where") and continuous elements ("keep the workload of a production site below 0.7"), 
and also non-linear constraints, MIP is not applicable.

Since we do have a somewhat complex model already in MiniZinc (we are currently using Google OR-Tools), I am wondering which MiniZinc-compatible solver provides most support for floating decision variables (maybe interval-based). Choco, JaCoP, Gecode .... ?

Otherwise, what could be similar high-level modeling languages that deal with continuous problems better? AMPL?

Thankful for your hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the coin-or open-source solvers like "couenne" can be used via MiniZn. You can follow the instruction of installation in [this](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.0/en/solvers.html#non-linear-solvers) link.

**Info about Couenne:**
Couenne (**C**onvex **O**ver and **U**nder **EN**velopes for **N**onlinear **E**stimation) is a branch&bound algorithm to solve Mixed-Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) problems and aims at finding global optima of nonconvex MINLPs.

Other than that, you can use [BARON](https://minlp.com/baron) solver for free if you send your model to [NEOS server](https://neos-server.org/neos/). BARON guarantees global optimal for MINLPs.

**Info about Baron:**
BARON (**B**ranch **a**nd **R**educe **O**ptimization **N**avigator) revolutionized global optimization technology in 2001 when it became the first commercial optimization software to offer deterministic guarantee for global optimality of nonlinear and mixed-integer nonlinear problems. Since then, BARON has remained the most complete and robust solver in global optimization technology.

Comment: Couenne and Ipopt do a really great job on our problem, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

Of the constraint based solvers JaCoP (https://github.com/radsz/jacop ) and Gecode (https://www.gecode.org/) has support for float decision variables combined with nonlinear constraints. Choco (https://choco-solver.org/ ) is supposed to have support for float variables but I got errors when running float variable models.

I would also add ECLiPSe CLP's ic solver (https://eclipseclp.org/ ) to the list, though it's a bit extra work to make it work with the MiniZinc tool-chain (one have to create some wrappers for the output etc).

My personal preference right now is JaCoP which seems to be quite stable for float variables + non linear constraint problems.

Note that for solving for float variables one have to be a little careful when using the `solve :: float_search` command. One might have to tweak the second argument (precision ) a little to get useful values (and good enough run time), e.g.

```
solve :: float_search(x, 0.001, input_order, indomain_split, complete) minimize z;
```